# How I can close pdf document after Output

Tags: tcpdf

This is my first post.

I have a problem because the window where I see my pdf document not close after I use:

```php
$pdf->Output('/document.pdf', 'F');
```

What's the problem ?

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Does your PHP user really have rights to write to the system root? ( `/` )

Comment: Yes !.. The pdf document is save in the directory !. But, the  window remains open  in white.....

Comment: there is some form that salve the pdf document   without display it ??

Comment: There is no problem; it's behaving precisely how it is supposed to behave. Try this `$pdf->Output('/document.pdf', 'F'); header('Location: https://www.google.com');`

Comment: Yes ! I solved this problem.

Comment: A last question. I  replace code how is in this link: http://www.bitrealm.net/2010/08/tcpdf-is-slow-here-is-the-solution/ . But, my document pdf is very slow.  Also, I use the TCPDF  indications in the official page:  http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php  , but is equal,  the pdf document is slow !. How I can  improve  performance ?